# How to Wrap Text in a Content Editable Div Per Line

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I would like to understand if I can wrap text in a content editable div.

For example, if a user uses markup to type

`### MY TITLE`

can I somehow parse that line and create another div that outputs

`<b>MY TITLE<b>`

I've created a jsfiddle to observe the output, but I don't see much that tells me where a line ENDS to put the closing tag. In addition, the output looks pretty weird after hitting the return key a couple times. It seems difficult to work with and I was hoping there be better indicators of what the user had typed.

```
"
        ### test 
        &lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rn2camL4/1/

Comment: Please post your code here as a snippet

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you just want to put bold tags around the output, if so, you can accomplish this with a simple concatenation.

I brought your jsfiddle over into the snippet below, please run it to see it in action.

When you `console.log(boldHtml)` you will see the output wrapped in `<b></b>`.

```js
$('#editable').on('keydown', function(e) {
  let html = $(this).html();
  //concatenate bold tags around your html and declare new boldHtml variable
  let boldHtml = '<b>' + html + '</b>'
  $('#render').html(boldHtml) // replace test with <b>test</b>
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true" style="background-color:white; outline: 0px solid transparent; width: 100%; padding: 16px;">
  ### test
</div>

<div id='render'>

</div>
```

Alternatively, if you're fine with using a library, you can use [markdown-it](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/markdown-it.) for example and have it convert any type of markdown into HTML.

I've applied the logic to your code below.

When you `console.log(markdown)` you will see the correct HTML tags around your output.

```js
const md = window.markdownit();


$('#editable').on('keydown', function(e) {
  let html = $(this).html();
  let markdown = md.render(html);
  $('#render').html(markdown) // replace any markdown with proper html

  //console.log(markdown);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markdown-it@10.0.0/dist/markdown-it.min.js"></script>

<div id="editable" contenteditable="true" style="background-color:white; outline: 0px solid transparent; width: 100%; padding: 16px;">
  Enter ANY markdown here
</div>

<div id='render'>

</div>
```